# I don't understand value given with sizeof() with Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

In this code snippet the output I get is 24. Why is that?

```
int data[] = { 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 0 };

int n = sizeof(data);

cout << n << endl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof` returns 24 because you have 6 integers, each taking 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must remember that `arrays` and `pointers` are different.

In case of an array, `sizeof()` returns the size of the whole array, which is 24 bytes in your example as you have 6 elements of `int`, and each is 4 bytes.

Now look at this code snippet:

```
int *data = { 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 0 };
int n = sizeof(data);
```

In this case, `sizeof()` will return the size of a pointer, not an array. A pointer is 4 bytes in a 32-bit app and 8 bytes in a 64-bit app.